# AWS Codebuild - DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED while

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-codebuild, cicd

```js
reports:
  jest_reports:
  arn:aws:codebuild:ap-south-1:831110728722:report-group/unittestreport
    files:
      - './output/report/unittest.xml'
    file-format: JUNITXML
    base-directory: './output/report'
    discard-paths: false
```

I'm Trying to create unit test report group in AWS codebuild but whenever i add the below reports syntax in buildspec.yml.

I'm facing [Container] 2021/12/08 10:25:15 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED and [Container] 2021/12/08 10:25:15 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: could not find expected ':' at line 22. Please help me on this.
Note :The buildspec.yml is working fine without reports syntax.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYou.png)
[buildspec.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KWEC.png)

Answer (score 0):

The colon is missing from the end of the report group ARN. You also can only specify either a report group name (which will create a new one for you) or the ARN of an existing one.

```
reports:
  arn:aws:codebuild:ap-south-1:ACCOUNT_ID_HERE:report-group/unittestreport:
    files:
      - './output/report/unittest.xml'
    file-format: JUNITXML
    base-directory: './output/report'
    discard-paths: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply craig. even after adding colon I'm getting the following error.

1. CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src127173520/src........

2. YAML location is /codebuild/output/src127173520/src/buildspec.yml.........

3. Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED..........

4. Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Expected unittestreport to be non-empty at line 21.............

Comment: Phase complete: **DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED**

Phase context status code: **YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Expected unittestreport to be non-empty at line 21**

Comment: need your help here...thanks

Comment: Hi @craig s -> It worked for me.. Thanks for your help :)